# Best solution for pulling updates of content from back end server?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

An iOS app which consumes content from back end server. The content actually does not need change with high frequence, just changed in the case of modifying the defected content.

The Apple Push Notification should be the best solution to push the update notifications to the device which installed the app, and then user can press maybe "update" option button to pull the lastest content after viewing the notifications.

Question is:  Is this the best solution for such cases ? If no, why ? and any better solution ? 
Or how about just pull the lastest content each time the app is launched ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically agree with [Vignesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562851/439529), but considering, that APNS requires also a server side work, I would start from polling on each entering foreground event, as it seems the simplest solution, and after it switch to APNS, when server side is ready, since it will require really less time, cause all the code will be already written.

**UPDATE**

To improve polling solution you may add last update date into NSUserDefaults to perform updates once in a day or so. Also you may wrap your Back End Server Proxy method call (request sending and processing) into background task to prevent interrupting it user taps home or perform multithreading gesture.

Comment: Agree with that the most simple approach would be polling during specific period by sending update request to back end server. The next question would be when ? Obviously "app launch" is not good time because it will go to background state once launched. The final best approach would be APN based, but need a lot of effort.

Comment: I didn't get the "_Obviously "app launch" is not good time because it will go to background state once launched_". Could you please clarify it. Are you working on app working in background? Even if so, it won't go the the background immediately after launch, only if user transfer it to the background.

Comment: What happens if the push notification does not get delivered ? APNS does not guarantee delivery of messages does it ?

Answer (score 1):

APNS is the best way to do it since you have specified your "data does not need change with high frequence".In my opinion Polling server every time for such a static kind of data is overkill and unnecessary.